# Spring Cloud config server disable encryption and decryption endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encryption, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to disable encrypt and decrypt end points in spring cloud config server.
My Bootstrap.yml file is

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        encrypt:
          enabled: false

encrypt:
  keyStore:
    location: ####
    password: ####
    alias: ####
    secret: ###
```

I tried this properties file with different verions of spring cloud and spring boot
Tried spring boot version 1.5.8.RELEASE and springCloudVersion = 'Dalston.SR4'

also tried

springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
and
springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.SR1'

but still I encryption and decryption endpoints are working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Spring Security to block this URI, with this configuration endpoint URLs are not publicly available.

```
package com.debopam.configserver;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 * @author Debopam
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("configUser").password("configPassword").roles("SYSTEM")
            .and()
        .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("SUPERUSER","ADMIN")
            .and()
        .withUser("actuator").password("actuator").roles("ACTUATOR");;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/encrypt**").hasAnyRole("SUPERUSER","ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/decrypt**").hasAnyRole("SUPERUSER","ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().hasRole("SYSTEM").and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too was thinking of adding spring security but the problem with this solution is my other apps which need configuration need to provide authentication. But I don't want to do that with other apps. I just want to block encrypt and decrypt end points with spring security(or any other way) and make all the end points public

Comment: I will use a permit all on all other request and block only encrypt and decrypt end points.

Comment: @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
   
            .antMatchers("/encrypt**").hasAnyRole("SUPERUSER","ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/decrypt**").hasAnyRole("SUPERUSER","ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().csrf()
            
           .disable();

    }          I modified it like this. Thanks!

Comment: You can use following proprties in Spring cloud to access it using userid password spring.cloud.config.name=<app name>
spring.cloud.config.username=configUser
spring.cloud.config.password=configPassword

Comment: If you want to use the encrypt or decrypt operation, how should the request (curl) be?

Comment: You add authorization information curl -u username:password https://...... OR curl -u 'username:password' https://.... OR curl -H "Authorization: OAuth <ACCESS_TOKEN>" http://.....